# Laravel SPA (Vue) Authentication with cookie or token?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, single-page-application, laravel-sanctum

the more I read about Laravel Spa (Vue) authentication, the more I ask myself about the "best way" to authenticate with Sanctum.
Official Laravel documentation says:

> For this feature, Sanctum does not use tokens of any kind. Instead,
> Sanctum uses Laravel's built-in cookie based session authentication
> services. This approach to authentication provides the benefits of
> CSRF protection, session authentication, as well as protects against
> leakage of the authentication credentials via XSS.

But a lot of videos on YouTube or other tutorials on the internet all using (bearer) tokens which sounds contradictory to me. I mean, just using a single token for authentication seems to be a bit unsafe to me.
Also, some of those people defined "login" and "register" routes directly into Laravels route file, instead of using Vue router.

I'm using Laravel 8, VueJS 3 and Vuex 4.

So, what do you think: Am I on the right way by using Vue routes and sanctum authentication using cookies or not? And why?

Thank you, I appreciate that.

Comment: I would say, people use tokens cause it's easy (to understand, to implement, etc...) and also easy to make it unsafe (where to store the token, expiration of the token).
Cookies are safer but harder to understand. If you have a library (like Sanctum) that does all the hard work for you, use it.

Comment: @jeremycastelli That's a good explanation.